# AmazonS3Exception: request signature error only in linux remote server?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, sdk, aws-sdk

I wrote a Java program to list all the buckets and to upload a file in S3 compatible Object storage service.
The program is working fine in Windows my local machine but when I (after changing the path of the file to be uploaded of course ) transfer the runnable jar in the remote linux server and execute it I'm getting the following error-

```
> Exception in thread "main"
> com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The request
> signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided.
> Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. For more
> information, see REST Authentication and SOAP Authentication for
> details. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code:
> SignatureDoesNotMatch; Request ID:
> 4e271b5b-d7f5-42b3-a4ad-886988bcb785; S3 Extended Request ID: null),
> S3 Extended Request ID: null
```

The issue seems to be in the 2nd half of the program as the list of buckets are returning in linux env. as well but during the file upload it is throwing error.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.S3ClientOptions;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.Bucket;

/**
 * List your Amazon S3 buckets.
 */
public class ListBuckets
{
    private static void listObjects(AmazonS3 s3) {
        List<Bucket> buckets = s3.listBuckets();
        System.out.println("Your Amazon S3 buckets are:");
        for (Bucket b : buckets) {
            System.out.println("* " + b.getName());
        }
    }
    private static void putObject(AmazonS3 s3, String bucketName, String objectName, String pathName) throws Exception
{

    s3.putObject(bucketName, objectName, new File(pathName));


}
private static void time(String t) {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();
    System.out.println(t+"-->"+dateFormat.format(date));
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    final String accessKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    final String secretKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    final AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
    S3ClientOptions opts = new S3ClientOptions().withPathStyleAccess(true);
    s3.setS3ClientOptions(opts);

    s3.setEndpoint("https://XXXXXX.com");
    ListBuckets.time("startTime");
    ListBuckets.listObjects(s3);
    //String pathName = "C:\\Users\\XXXXXX\\Documents\\New folder\\New Text Document - Copy.txt";
    String pathName = "/home/abcd/XXXXX/objectStorage/CHANGELOG.mdown";
    ListBuckets.putObject(s3, "snap-shot/sample-aws-ex", pathName, pathName);
    ListBuckets.time("end time");
}
```

}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unbelievable! 
You know what the issue was in linux? The object name and path name are two different things.

```
putObject(AmazonS3 s3, String bucketName, String objectName, String pathName)
```

where the pathName is the path of your file i.e.

```
String pathName = "/home/abc/xxxxx/objectStorage/errorlog.txt";
```

Notice it starts with forward slash, whereas object name should not start with `/` i.e.

```
String objectName = "home/abc/xxxxxx/objectStorage/errorlog.txt";
```

I wish the exception thrown would have given better clarity on what was wrong. The exception thrown only made me deviate from the root cause.